# Can apply function change the original input pandas df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, immutability

I always assume that the apply function won't change the original pandas dataframe and need the assignment to return the changes, however, could anyone help to explain why this happen?

```
def f(row):
    row['a'] = 10
    row['b'] = 20
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,11,12], 'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[1,1,1]}) #, 'd':[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
df_x.apply(f, axis = 1)
df_x
```

returns

```
    a   b   c
0   10  20  1
1   10  20  1
2   10  20  1
```

So, apply function changed the original pd.DataFrame without return, but if there's an non-basic type column in the data frame, then it won't do anything:

```
def f(row):
    row['a'] = 10
    row['b'] = 20
    row['d'] = [0]
    
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,11,12], 'b':[3,4,5], 'c':[1,1,1], 'd':[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]})
df_x.apply(f, axis = 1)
df_x
```

This return result without any change

```
    a   b   c   d
0   10  3   1   [1, 2]
1   11  4   1   [1, 2]
2   12  5   1   [1, 2]
```

Could anyone help to explain this or provide some reference? thx

Comment: use `df_x = df_x.apply(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Series are mutable objects. If you modify them during an operation, the changes will be reflected **if no copy is made**.

This is what happens in the first case. My guess: no copy is made as your DataFrame has a homogenous dtype (integer), so all the DataFrame is stored as a unique array internally.

In the second case, you have at least one item being a list. This make the dtype `object`, the DataFrame not a single dtype and `apply` must generate a new Series before running due to the mixed type of the row.

You can actually reproduce this just by changing a single element to another type:

```
def f(row):
    row['a'] = 10
    row['b'] = 20
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,11,12],
                     'b':[3,4,5],
                     'c':[1,1.,1]}) # float
df_x.apply(f, axis = 1)
df_x

# different types
# no mutation
    a  b    c
0  10  3  1.0
1  11  4  1.0
2  12  5  1.0
```

**Take home message:** never modify a mutable input in a function (unless you want it and know what you're doing).